# How can I vectorise a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

This is part of deep learning where I have implementated the forward propagation with explicit loops, but I'm stuck as to how to do with only numpy vectorised operations.

```
def forward(self, input_t):
    output_t = np.zeros_like(input_t)
    for i in range(input_t.shape[0]):
        curr = input_t[i, :] - np.max(input_t[i, :])
        output_t[i, :] = np.exp(curr) / np.sum(np.exp(curr))
    self.store = output_t
    return output_t
```

Comment: dont use `input` as a variable name, it is already in use by python for accepting user input from stream

Comment: Is this the softmax function?

Comment: yes, actually that's right:)) I'm getting stuck in this part to implement with numpy arrays. I did it with for-loop but have no clue for replacing it with numpy arrays.

Comment: @Kevin yes it is softmax function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about smth like this:

```
import numpy as np

def forward_loop(input_t):
    output_t = np.zeros_like(input_t)
    for i in range(input_t.shape[0]):
        curr = input_t[i, :] - np.max(input_t[i, :])
        output_t[i, :] = np.exp(curr) / np.sum(np.exp(curr))
    store = output_t
    return output_t

def forward(input_t):
    output_t = np.zeros_like(input_t)
    curr = input_t - np.max(input_t, axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
    output_t = np.exp(curr) / np.sum(np.exp(curr), axis = 1).reshape(-1,1)
    store = output_t
    return output_t


x = np.random.rand(3, 3)

print(f'x = \n{x}')
print(f'y_loop = \n{forward_loop(x)}')
print(f'y = \n{forward(x)}')
```

output:

```
x = 
[[0.98055614 0.0364636  0.07754052]
 [0.14524677 0.53440358 0.33880981]
 [0.0406863  0.14387749 0.08279181]]
y_loop = 
[[0.55729621 0.21680631 0.22589748]
 [0.27105399 0.40000412 0.32894188]
 [0.31728829 0.35177859 0.33093312]]
y = 
[[0.55729621 0.21680631 0.22589748]
 [0.27105399 0.40000412 0.32894188]
 [0.31728829 0.35177859 0.33093312]]
```

Comment: You can use ```keepdims=True``` instead of reshaping.